# Парсинг Ajax. Python + Requests

Tags: python, ajax, парсер, requests

Всем привет. Занимаюсь парсингом одного сайта, один из параметров - номер телефона владельца, но он изначально скрыт и подгружается с помощью ajax'а.

При нажатии на кнопку "показать телефон" во вкладке **Network** в разделе **Response** пишет только **"OK"**. При составлении post запроса такой же ответ.

**Вопрос**: Какими способами можно достать номер телефона, используя: **python + requests**

Comment: Случаем не авито? :D

Comment: @gil9red Не авито, но похожий сайт.

Comment: Если через ajax не приходит, ищите номер в предыдущих запросах. Возможно, он на самой странице находится, но закодирован. Когда [занимался](https://github.com/gil9red/ads_sites_parser) парсингом сайтов-объявлений, я на каком-то сайте увидел номер телефона в base64, а тот после клика просто декодировался и показывался.

Comment: Кст, если хотите получить таки точный ответ на ваш вопрос, лучше ссылку предоставить :)

Comment: @gil9red http://www.realestate.ru/flatrent/4274613/
пожалуйста)

Comment: Смогу посмотреть ссылку после 16 -- корпоративный белый список. Возможно сами разберетесь или ответят вам :)

Comment: @gil9red да мне не срочно) Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Готово, ниже этого кода я напишу подробнее, что тут происходит:

```py
import math

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def decrypt_phone(clipped_phone, value):
    decrypt = value / 17

    p1 = int(math.floor(decrypt / 100))
    p2 = int(decrypt - 100 * p1)
    t1 = str(p1)[1:] + '-' + str(p2).zfill(2)

    return clipped_phone.replace("...", "") + t1


def get_phone(url):
    rs = requests.get(url)
    root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'lxml')

    button_show_phone = root.select_one('#show-phone_button')
    blst = int(button_show_phone['blst'])
    lst1 = int(button_show_phone['lst1'])
    lst2 = int(button_show_phone['lst2'])

    phones = []

    for phone_tag in root.select('.object-builder-phone'):
        if phone_tag.has_attr('blst') and phone_tag['blst'] == 'true':
            value = blst
        elif phone_tag.has_attr('lst1') and phone_tag['lst1'] == 'true':
            value = lst1
        elif phone_tag.has_attr('lst2') and phone_tag['lst2'] == 'true':
            value = lst2
        else:
            raise Exception('Отсутствует один из атрибутов: blst, lst1, lst2, или значение не "true"')

        phone = decrypt_phone(phone_tag.text, value)
        phones.append(phone)

    return phones


print(get_phone('http://www.realestate.ru/flatrent/4274613/'))
print(get_phone('http://www.realestate.ru/retailrent/176651/'))
print(get_phone('http://www.realestate.ru/retailrent/180232/'))
```

Консоль:

```
['+7 495 626-84-44']
['+7 964 718-31-13']
['+7 926 777-01-75', '+7 926 777-01-84']
```

---

Телефон и вправду был на странице, но закодирован.
У кнопки показать телефон (`#show-phone_button`) есть волшебные атрибуты `blst`, `lst1` и `lst2`. Один из атрибутов хранит оставшиеся 4 цифры телефона, скрытые от любопытных глаз.

То, какой атрибут использовать зависит от тега с обрезанным номером телефона (`.object-builder-phone`). В теге есть один атрибутов `blst`, `lst1` и `lst2` с значением `"true"`.

Сам скрипт, в котором обрабатывает клик на кнопку показать телефон, декодировка номера и замена, называется `shared.js` (см. рисунок).

*`shared.js` я нашел случайно – просто тыкал и смотрел скрипты, т.к. поиск по `show-phone_button` ничего не дал, даже когда открыл тот скрипт*

А вот так выглядит функция декодирования (я ее переписал как `decrypt_phone`):

```
function ShowAttr(e, attr, value)
{
    if ($(e).attr(attr) == "true")
    {
        var decrypt = value / 17;
        var p1 = Math.floor(decrypt / 100);
        var p2 = decrypt - 100 * p1;
        var t1 = ("" + p1).substring(1) + '-' + pad(p2, 2);
        $(e).text($(e).text().replace("...", "") + t1);
        $(e).attr(attr, 'false');
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отлично! Еще раз спасибо вам)

Comment: @АлександрКурмазов, пожалуйста )